# Horizontally Align to center

Tags: javascript, html, css

utterly complete beginner here, I have a button that I really would like to align to center but are unsure on how to do so.. Does anybody know what to do? I've tried a couple of different item-align, class, layout-align, style... Is there anyone who can help? and explain what goes wrong? I have a hard time understanding what to do from other similar questions.. Cheers!

Comment: text-align:center;

Comment: Do you want to align the button itself or the text inside it?